# Updating address bar with current url from UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Like iPhone safari browser, I want to update `UItextview` with current url of `UIWebView`

I tried `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method, but I end up with url of some ads/iframe

If I use `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method, then address bar gets updated at the end of the request.

Please help me on the best approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `mainDocumentURL` method on the NSURLRequest in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`. This should contain the main document URL regardless of whether the page is loading or a resource on the page (e.g. a frame) is loading.

Comment: This works, Thanks. Another small issue, how to avoid updating multiple times for the same url?

Comment: You can hold onto the last URL you saw and just test to see if the next request uses the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `webviewDidFinishLoad` when delegated from your webview, and then query it for the title with [`webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]` or `weboutWebView.request.URL.absoluteString` for the url.